# problem with join query

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to select all the tags that go with a post in my database, but for some reason, I'm only getting one tag for every post that has tags.

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post_title, t.tag_id, t.tag_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to extract all posts, with all the tags associated to the posts, the query is correct. If you think it's not - check your data. If you want to limit it to only one post, add a WHERE clause.

Comment: Your query is correct. You´re having all the tags in multiple rows for each post

Comment: you guys are right, I was expecting the rows from post to be empty when a post had multiple tags, that's why I didn't notice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each post can have many tags. What I'd suggest is using [MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and get all of the tags into one field. You can then parse that field in your script, if you need to.

**edit**
It appears that you are left joining on the tag table, therefore it is only returning that row for the tag. Try switching around the tables in your `ON` clause so that it joins the other direction. You'll then need to iterate over the results (now that it should have a row per tag.) My original solution grouped all of the tags into one field.

Comment: you seem to suggest a way to get one row from the tags. The problem seems to be that this is already the case  "I'm only getting one tag for every post that has tags"

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine. In fact because its close to the SO data structure I created one using data.stackexchange.com and it works fine [there](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/917/query-for-http-stackoverflow-com-q-4938406-119477)